# 4 Pole Connector and USB cable compatibility

Tags: usb, connector, impedance, shielding

USB 2.0 Cable to pass through enclosure boxes.

Are such cables able to be cut and connected (soldered) to the connectors pictured, and used without effect on their performance.
[image][image]

Are there specific steps to take with regard to the shielding and the separation of the wires to reduce the effects of impedance?

Thanks

Comment: There are specific USB Bulkhead connectors.

Answer (score 1):

> Are such cables able to be cut and connected (soldered) to the connectors pictured, and used without effect on their performance.

Can't tell you, because we don't have a spec sheet to these connectors.

USB2 is a (pseudo)differential bidirectional bus, and it relies on the cables being of defined impedance. If your connectors are designed to keep that impedance without sharp transitions, then they're fine, if you know how to properly attach your wires AND the shield to them.

The connectors you show don't look they are impedance-controlled, and especially not for a USB-typical impedance, but that's just a guess. Get a datasheet. If you can't get a datasheet, or the datasheet doesn't mention wave impedance, get a different connector.

I'd say: Looking at these connectors, you probably *can't* make a fully USB2-compliant connection with them.

That doesn't matter for low speed (~1 Mbd) and full speed (~12 Mbd) devices as much, but if you really want to do hi speed USB2 (~480 Mb), you won't have much success.

There are ruggedized and waterproof industrial USB connectors, by the way. [Not all are a good idea](https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1195487970167414784.html).

Comment: Thankyou Marcus.  Your answer discounts this method and is therefore appreciated.

Comment: @enginology no, it doesn't. It just says before you use **any** connector, you need to read its datasheet.